# How to show specific div element if there is a set limit in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this rails app that I want to achieve.

How do you auto show the static div element if the conditions `limit(4)` is showing 4 div elements? What I want to achieve is when 4 post boxes are displayed in the browser, This will only show the static element for `Apply for our  Program` div element.

```
<div class="row">
    <% @posts.limit(4).each do |post| %>
        <h2> <% post.title %> </h2>
    <% end %>
</div

<div class="row">
   <div class="border-box">
      <h1>Apply for our Program</h1>
      <a href="#">Link to Program</a>
   </div>
</div
```

I want to only show this static div element if the 4 posts are displayed. Unless hiding this static div element if posts are not equal to 4.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="border-box">
      <h1>Apply for our Program</h1>
      <a href="#">Link to Program</a>
   </div>
</div
```

Is there a special function in a rails app that counts the div displayed if it is equal to 4 then displays the static div element. Or Do I need Jquery function for this one to show the static element if the count  is equal to 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need any JS. Simply place your second div inside

```
<% if @posts.count >= 4 %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Definitely resolve the issue.. Thank you for this one. (bow)

Comment: Also note that if you previously loaded ``@posts`` in your controller, calling ``@posts.limit(4)`` will still run another SQL query. Calling ``@posts.first(4)`` will give you (up to) the first four records without re-running a query.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with Javascript IF you need to animate, or manage show/hiding based on other event rather than number of post.

I'll show you in jQuery, but this can be made easily with plain JS

```
<div class="row">
 <% @posts.limit(4).each do |post| %>
    <h2> <% post.title %> </h2>
 <% end %>
</div>

<div class="row box--apply hidden">
  <div class="border-box">
    <h1>Apply for our Program</h1>
    <a href="#">Link to Program</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

where

```
.hidden { display:none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

and then in JS

```
$(function() {
  const nH2 = $('H2').length;
  const $box = $('.box--apply');

  if(nH2 >= 4) {
    $box.removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
  }
});
```

and, the logic can be expand based on your requirements.